# ASP.net member security access

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

We are looking at enhanching our current security access model which is basically a check if the user is logged in. We now require the acesss to modules and pages and possible certain sections in the page such as dropdown restrictions based on your role.

I'm not sure how to design but maybe a few pointers and writing the requirements here will help.

The user usually belongs to an company. 
The user usually has a role within that company
The company is made up of 1 or more sub companies
The user/role can have access to some modules in the system
The user/role can have access to some or all sub companies.
A role must be completely configurable on the fly.

A interface is required to configure the access for the users and the roles.

The menu needs to be configured based on access rights
The page needs to be configured based on access rights

We are using asp.net 2.0 at the moment but could possibly upgrade.

So based on that I think we need 
User, Group, Role ( but roles need to be configurable) and Modules
A role for one organisation may have same name but have access to completely different Modules.

I am not sure asp.net membership is suitable so would like some opinions as it seams that access to pages is all hardcoded in config etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ASP.Net Membership Provider` for what you have stated.

As you said you are using **ASP.Net 2.0**, you cannot use new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which is based on Entity Framework.

However, `Membership Provider` is introduced in ASP.Net 2.0. So you can still use the old version which uses `aspnet_regsql.exe` to create tables with the correct schema.

Here is the link for step-by-step instruction -

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

***Please note that you cannot migrate from `old ASP.Net 2.0 Membership` to new `Universal Providers`***.

Comment: I've been given to go ahead to say that we are upgrading to 4.0 so with that in mind what are my options now?

Comment: If so, you can use `new ASP.NET Universal Providers` for your scenario. If your website needs OAuth or OpenID, you might want to consider `SimpleMembershipProvider` - http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx